# C# Load XML into Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I have a string of XML that I want to load directly into a spreadsheet with C#. I've found a few examples but haven't quite been able to fill in the gaps in my knowledge.

```
Range r = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Range["A1", Missing.Value];
Workbook w = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
w.XmlImportXml(xmlString, out map1, true, r);
```

It seems that the "map1" variable would be the mapping of the XML schema. How do I do this? Do I have to specify an .xsd file or can this be created programmatically? What is the preferred way to handle this?

My XML layout is similar to:

```
<root>
   <parent>
      <childOne>5</childOne>
      <childTwo>8</childTwo>
   </parent>
   <parent>
      <childOne>10</childOne>
      <childTwo>15</childTwo>
   </parent>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the XML into a Datatable before like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.ReadXml(xmlFilePath); // new StringReader(xmlContent)

Excel.XmlMap map = w.XmlMaps.Add(table.GetXmlSchema(), "WhatEver");
w.XmlImportXml(table.GetXml(), out map, true, r);
```

I dont know from where you get the xml-content. If you got it as a string allready, use the ReadXML overload that accepts a textreader.

Also check those links
[Functionexample of XmlImportXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbookbase.xmlimportxml%28v=vs.85%29), 
[DataTable from Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z447ey0x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Is this System.Data.DataTable? It appears that that class does not have a GetXmlSchema() method

Comment: Check the second link i provided

Comment: I think that even with that example I have the same problem. I need to be able to generate an XML schema for passing to XmlMaps.Add(). I posted a separate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898861/generate-xml-schema-from-xml-string