# Preferred Method for Loading XML Data Into Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I've been spinning in circles trying to get XML data loaded into an Excel worksheet.

I started with transforming the XML into a List of Objects and then iterating that List, outputting each individual row. I discovered some posts that said this was inefficient, however, and abandoned the idea.

I then attempted the XmlImportXml method, but having quite gotten this to work yet. (See [Generate XML Schema From XML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898861/generate-xml-schema-from-xml-string))

Are there any other alternatives to loading XML data into an Excel worksheet?

Is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: After some research, I went with the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range